# Can't connect to web socket react-native-meteor iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-meteor

I'm using react-native-meteor, and am having trouble connecting to the web socket with iOS only.  My application works just fine when running on the android simulator, but just doesn't work in iOS simulator or device.  This is my code:

```
Meteor.connect('ws://app.mysite.com/websocket');
```

And the logs:

```
[info][tid:main][RCTBatchedBridge.m:72] Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x7fe23b23d4c0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x7fe239d65090>, executor: RCTJSCExecutor)
[warn][tid:main][RCTEventEmitter.m:54] Sending `websocketFailed` with no listeners registered.


Disconnected from DDP server.
```

Any idea why I can't connect on iOS only?

I have already disabled App Transport Security, and downloaded a non-https webpage, so I know that's not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out.  I think I had incorrectly configured the app transport security exception.  To fix it, I connected to the secure web socket like this (note the extra s):

```
Meteor.connect('wss://app.mysite.com/websocket');
```